# Can't set docker-machine environment variables bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, fish

I' using bash 4.3 and I can't export or set docker-machine environment variables

```
bash-4.3$ docker-machine env default
set -gx DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY "1";
set -gx DOCKER_HOST "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376";
set -gx DOCKER_CERT_PATH "/Users/ofolorunso/.docker/machine/machines/default";
set -gx DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME "default";
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval (docker-machine env default)
```

Apparently bash doesn't recognize the `g` flag

```
bash-4.3$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

I should note that my machine's default shell is `fish`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried forcing bash with the `--shell` option?

```
docker-machine env --shell bash default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH "/Users/ofolorunso/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
```

Env variables are set with `set -gx` in fish and with `export` in bash.

Comment: To expand a bit on this answer. If your login shell is fish and you type `bash` to start a bash shell the `$SHELL` env var will still refer to the fish command; e.g., /usr/local/bin/fish. That in turn will confuse a program like `docker-machine` which examines `$SHELL` to decide how to set variables in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Set has no flag -g in bash. I do not know what you're trying to do with those flags, but if you want to set environment or shell variables, look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/).

For example, to set a variable use something like this: `export ANT_HOME=/path/to/ant/dir`